# How to call JS from native Java code?

Tags: java, javascript, android, cordova

How can I call a simple event or execute a JavaScript function in native Android code with Cordova?

I tried

```
    public void notificationRecieved(String heading,String news){
        try{
            if(webview!=null){
                Log.i("PUSHPARSE","in Notification Received Event");
                //webview.loadUrl("javascript:alert('URLcall')");
                webview.sendJavascript("alert('CAlling from Java')");
            }   

        }catch(Exception e1){
            Log.e("PUSHPARSE",e1.getMessage(),e1);
        }

    }
```

I am not able to get any notification or alert.

**Update**

Logcat shows `I/PUSHPARSE( 2039): in Notification Received Event`

Tried doing 
`webview.loadUrl("http://www.google.com");`

the logs show

```
>>> loadUrl(http://www.google.com)

W/CordovaWebView( 2039): CordovaWebView.init() was not called. This will soon be required.

D/CordovaWebView( 2039): CordovaWebView is running on device made by: unknown
```

Comment: are you sure webview is the cordova webview? and it is initialized? that code should work, or try with webview.loadUrl("javascript:console.log('test');"); and look into logcat to see if the log appears

Comment: I did that.. still no output. is there any other way to dispatch or call an event from Java to JS.?

Comment: is the Log.i("PUSHPARSE","in Notification Received Event"); being displayed on the log?

Comment: yes that gets logged. but just after the call it vanishes inside Cordova call. No exception or trace.

Answer (score 1):

I guess alert is not working in webview try document.write or console.log for see

Thanks

Comment: thanks for reply, what do you want me to write in document? a script for alert? or so?

Comment: i guess alert('x') not working on webview may be it works  webview.loadUrl("javascript:document.write('URLcall')");
or
webview.sendJavascript("javascript:document.write('URLcall')");

and console.log can writes your eclipse console

Answer (score 0):

May be you can use the pushPlugin  https://github.com/phonegap-build/PushPlugin and use method function onNotification(e) ?